# inconsistent ticker data from websocket

Tags: coinbase-api

I am successfully listening to the ticker websocket feed of gdax, but I have noticed the data that is send through the feed for tickers it not consistent. In particular, almost all ticks contain the all the data as specified on the API, but once in a while a tick will be send through the websocket with incomplete data.

An example of an incomplete tick would be:

```
{
  "type": "ticker",
  "sequence": 3282742809,
  "product_id": "BTC-EUR",
  "price": "8990.40000000",
  "open_24h": "9364.00000000",
  "volume_24h": "1926.69377604",
  "low_24h": "8990.40000000",
  "high_24h": "9393.23000000",
  "volume_30d": "119293.98845262",
  "best_bid": "8990.39",
  "best_ask": "8990.4"
}
```

For these cases, some fields are missing such at the 'time' field.

It seems to be completely arbitrary, although it does (almost?) always seem to happen for the first tick.
Has anyone encountered similar issues?

Comment: I experience the same thing, and just decided to skip the ticks missing the time